# Create a python regular expression for finding 1 to 4 chars uppercase

Tags: python, regex

I already have the following regular expression:

```
'([A-Z0-9]{1,4}(?![A-Z0-9]))'
```

that meets the following requirements.

- 1-4 Characters in length
- All Uppercase
- Can be a mix of numbers and
  letters

Now Say I have this string "This is A test of a TREE, HOUSE"

```
result = ['T', 'A', 'TREE']
```

I don't want the first 'T' because it is not on it's own and is part of a word.

How would I go about modifying the re search to account for this?

Thanks

[Edit: Spelling]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**word boundaries** `\b`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#wordboundary) around your pattern.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'This is A test of a TREE, HOUSE'
>>> re.findall(r'\b[A-Z0-9]{1,4}\b', s)
['A', 'TREE']
```